# Set labelText color, but respect error validation color

Tags: flutter

I have a TextFormField with a labelText. I would like the labelText to be orange, unless when the form validation fails, then the text should be standard error red.

[image]

But if I put a TextStyle in the decoration options, and setting the color to orange, this text style overrides the standard validation color:

```
TextFormField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
       labelText: 'I want to be orange',
       labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.orange),
   ),
   validator: (value) {
       if (value == null || value.isEmpty || value != 'test') {
           return 'Validation error';
       }
       return null;
     },
   ),
```

[image]

I can´t seem to find any properties on the TextFormField that supports this case. I also searched for a solution where I could set the TextStyle based on the status of the validation, but it seems like it is not possible to access the validation state inside the TextFormField.

One would think this is a pretty common case. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the labelColor inside a variable

```
  Color labelColor = Colors.orange;
```

Inside your validate you can set the color to red

```
validator: (value) {
       if (value == null || value.isEmpty || value != 'test') {
           setState(() {
            labelColor = Colors.red;
           });
           return 'Validation error';
       }
       return null;
     },
```

Set the color as the labelColor

```
labelStyle: TextStyle(color: labelColor),
```

Comment: Well that does technically answer my question. Thanks!
But in my project I have Wrapped a TextFormField in another widget component and my validators are defined in their own files. So to use this solution I must move all my different validators into my wrapped TextFormField component so they are part of the widget context and state. I not too keen on this, but I´ll guess I must describe my problem in better detail in another question :)